# Colab connection always broken

Tags: python

I run CNN code on Colab notebook, and it takes long time. However, the connection always breaks after I ran 2 or 3 hours and cannot be reconnect back. I was told Colab virture machine would break connection after 12 hours without any operates, so how can I avoid restart my code after connection broken, or any easier way to controll Colab?

Answer (score 0):

Colab restarts on inactivity in 2-3 hours, you need to reconnect it. To simply avoid this show some activity on runtime.